# New Activity crashes when button is clicked

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to build an app to keep track of groceries. I have it divided into food groups. The button that opens the Food food group opens normally, the second button however it crashes. It is called Dairy button. 
Every time that I click on the Dairy button the app crashes. Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

here is my code for MainActivity.java

```
package apps.fsc.foodtracker;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.sax.StartElementListener;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import apps.fsc.foodtracker.R;

// This program exists solely to generate a database and play with it.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText userEntryText;
    TextView resultsText;
    myDBManager dbManager;
    private Button fruitButton;
    private Button dairyButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fruitButton = findViewById(R.id.fruitButton);
        fruitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                OpenFruit();
            }

        });

        dairyButton = findViewById(R.id.dairyButton);
        dairyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                OpenDairy();
            }
        });


        // Grab references to UI elements
        userEntryText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userEntryText);
        resultsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultsText);

        // dbManager reference
        dbManager = new myDBManager(this, null, null, 1);

        // Let's see what's in the database.
        printDatabase();
    }

public void OpenFruit()
    {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Fruit.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
public void OpenDairy()
    {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Dairy.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
    }

    public void printDatabase() {
        // Query the database using the dbManager's dbToString() method.
        String dbString = dbManager.dbToString();
        // Drop the results onto the UI
        resultsText.setText(dbString);
        // Set the UI up for fresh input
        userEntryText.setText("");
    }

    public void addButtonClick(View view) {
        // Create a new product based on what's in the UI
        Products product = new Products(userEntryText.getText().toString());
        // Send that product object to the dbManager so the item can be added.
        dbManager.addItem(product);
        // See what's in the database
        printDatabase();

    }

    public void delButtonClick(View view) {
        // Grab the UI contents and dump it into a string
        String inputText = userEntryText.getText().toString();
        // Send that string to the dbManager's delItem() method.
        dbManager.delItem(inputText);
        // See what's in the database
        printDatabase();
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: _"the app crashes"_ Post the stacktrace.

Comment: You have to tell us what the error is at least

Comment: I do not have an error code. It simply crashes the android emulator when I click on the Dairy Button which is supposed to open a new activity.

Comment: Is there a way to get error codes?

Comment: By grabbing the logcat output.

Comment: 03-12 16:21:25.085 10160-10160/apps.fsc.foodtracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: apps.fsc.foodtracker, PID: 10160
                                                                      android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {apps.fsc.foodtracker/apps.fsc.foodtracker.Dairy}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.

Comment: I solved it. I had no idea where to find the error codes. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Supply your manifest. 
As you must declare Activitys in your AndroidManifest.xml file like so

For your Fruit Activity:

```
<activity android:name=".Fruit" />
```

For your Dairy Activity:

```
<activity android:name=".Dairy" />
```

3-12 16:21:25.085 10160-10160/apps.fsc.foodtracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: apps.fsc.foodtracker, PID: 10160 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {apps.fsc.foodtracker/apps.fsc.foodtracker.Dairy};***have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? ***

Thats what is says in the error messenge.